# Specify exclusive joining of union types in a Typescript generic type

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to specify a generic type that is *one of* two possible union types, but cannot contain non-overlapping elements from either type?

Here's what I want to do:

```
  type TrueFalseType = "true" | "false"
  type ABType = "A" | "B"
  
  const myFunction = <T extends ABType | TrueFalseType>(values: Array<T>) => {
    console.log(values)
  }
  
  myFunction(["A", "B"]) // should be allowed
  myFunction(["true", "false"]) // should be allowed
  myFunction(["A", "false"]) // should be compile error
```

This isn't working as intended, because the final line is compiling when I want it to be an error.
How can I change the generic type definition to allow ONLY a type T that is `ABType` OR `TrueFalseType` but not element from either/both?

Comment: As stated I'd make `T` an array type and not the element type, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpAZXW) (and then `T[number]` would be your old `T`), but then there's no reason this needs to be generic at all, since [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3Ep2w) works the same way.  Do either of those meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, please [edit] to show use cases that are unmet.

Comment: @jcalz super helpful, thank you! Both of these satisfy what I need, and the non-generic solution is even simpler, so that's helpful. Thank you for the insight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straightforward approach is to abandon [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and just have `values` be the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the two different array types you want to support:

```
const myFunction = (values: ABType[] | TrueFalseType[]) => {
  console.log(values)
}

myFunction(["A", "B"]) // okay
myFunction(["true", "false"]) // okay
myFunction(["A", "false"]) // error
```

Since `["A", "false"]` is neither an `ABType[]` nor a `TrueFalseType[]`, it is rejected.

---

If for some reason you need generics, you should probably still express it in terms of the type of `values`, and [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) your type parameter to that same union of array types:

```
const myFunction = <U extends ABType[] | TrueFalseType[]>(values: U) => {
  type T = U[number];
  console.log(values)
}
```

Here I've named the type parameter `U` just to make it obvious that it's not the same as your `T`, which is the array *element* type.  If you need to compute that, you can do so by [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `U` with `number` (since indexing into an array with a numeric key yields the array element).  That is, `type T = U[number]`.

This behaves the same as far as callers are concerned:

```
myFunction(["A", "B"]) // okay
myFunction(["true", "false"]) // okay
myFunction(["A", "false"]) // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUIUkqJLAsgHID2wA4hMBAE4CW8e+xxALgJ4xkAFWYBXCADFMUCEIHIAvEgBEPMRGVIAPioBm0jV279BSAIIAhOaaXKzmncovKi3eLSg8kYPhNHB4HlZaJCUACgA3THEoAC5zK3kAbQBdbSQRcSkMGWsIVIBKUIA+Tm43D2oMCAA6DGoAc0jo6AKjYgBfV2IfPwCg2jCku2UAGhVnFKKAemmkagBrED52719-QODgIdV1Mb0DZSmkWfmllfLejYHt4ftx5X0cjWPTlmZqZiMuo1JoOEQSAYTDYHAI5RMwnU2Vy8lCKjU4gcB2eLghcMseXhI3SThcq3cwE8az6mxCSgAPABVJAQAAePEYABMoAk8ql0plJAZ2Slis0MDF4lSigpSuDykhIRl4VSksBRGAAEYsFIAblWxEJUCqtXqTSigtaqx+l3W-S2O3uEyOMzmUAAFtRRBgmUgVUhMPUAO4QJmrK4WwbDREaB5PGS2k72p0ut0er3UX3+s2km5W-aPQ6vGPO13u5DuMAwVjVWnMD5fTqEQhdIA)